Axiomatizability of inclusion over any powerset
Is class $(\mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq)$ for arbitrary $A$ axiomatizable? One of the assignments I got was to prove that it is not, but a friend of mine suggested this structure is a complete atomic Boolean Algebra (strictly speaking isomorphic to one) and thus axiomatazible since Boolean Algebras are axiomatizable.
So my question is whether his reasoning holds since what we have is order and not the boolean operators. Though I couldn't find any argument to prove the structure indeed isn't axiomatazible, so I'm in a pickle on this one.

Axiomatisable in what logic?

First Order Language

Being a complete Boolean algebra is not axiomatisable, since it requires quantifying over subsets. Case in point, DLS implies there's a countably infinite model, but there are not countably infinite complete Boolean algebras.

completeness is not axiomatizable since it requires quantifying over predicates.

Oh, ok. And could you give any direction for proving it is not axiomatizable? I tried using comptactness but as of now every argument I considered was flawed

@Rikimaru Asaf already gave a proof. If it were axiomatizable, then downward Löwenheim-Skolem would imply there is a countably infinite complete Boolean algebra. But there is no such thing.

@Rikimaru (Though, perhaps it is easier to directly show the class you give is not axiomatizable. Again, if it were, then by downward Löwenheim-Skolem there would be some $\mathcal{P}(A)$ which is countably infinite, but this is impossible - if $A$ is finite then $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is finite, if $A$ is infinite then $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is uncountable.)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716353/is-the-first-order-theory-of-complete-atomic-boolean-algebras-finitely-axiomatiz here is something contrary to what @Trebor and asaf said or am I not seeing something here

That is talking about something different. Do you want your axiomatization to only contain powersets as models? Or do you allow models that are not powersets, but satisfy all the same first order sentences? (In that case you can simply delete the word "complete" from the question.)

Only models that contain powerset (any powerset though)

In that case the linked question has nothing to do with your question.

ok something clicked and I got it, thanks for all the comments=)
